# What does "annoy the hell out of somebody" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

Source: [Embedded Content: Video, Audio, and Canvas](http://htmldog.com/guides/html/advanced/embeddedcontent/)

> This will play the video on page load, won’t display any controls, and will most likely **annoy the hell out of your visitors**. Of course you could, if you were kind, put in both the controls and autoplay attributes.

What does "annoy the hell out of somebody" mean? I guess it just means "annoy somebody". I wonder how can that phrase be logically explained?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's simply idiomatic.

> [the hell out of](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hell-out-of)
>   **very much:**
>   *You scared the hell out of me!*
>   Note: This may be considered offensive by some people.

So in the OP

> ... will most likely annoy your visitors *very much*.

This version is polite. The original is somewhat crude but feels more emphatic. For instance, imagine that you are a visitor to that page and you become very annoyed ([pissed](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pissed), in American slang). If you have no problems swearing (*hell* is a mild swear), then you might say *this page is annoying the hell out of me!* [= This is really, really annoying me!].

Note that the meaning *the hell out of* can differ depending on the context.

> [—— the hell out of](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/%E2%80%94%E2%80%94_the_hell_out_of)
>   *informal*
>   Used in verbal phrases to emphasize force, speed, etc.:
>   *'let's get the hell out of here'*

This would mean *let's leave fast/quickly*.

One more example: [Dad Trolls The Hell Out Of His Daughter’s Selfies](http://www.craveonline.com/mandatory/1164473-dad-trolls-hell-daughters-selfies#AJtZahMorxDQMgtL.99)

[image]

Here, the meaning is something like *dad thoroughly [makes fun of](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/make+fun+of) his daughter's selfies* or *dad does a good job of making fun of his daughter's selfies*.

Answer (score 1):

Swear words like "hell" are added for emphasis and rarely make literal sense. They just mean "very" or "a lot".

"He gave a _____ of a good performance." (Fill in the swear word of your choice.) -> "He gave a very good performance."

"That scared the _____ out of me." -> "That scared me a lot."

Etc.

In my humble opinion, one should always be cautious about using swear words. Some people think nothing of them. Others find them funny. Others find them deeply offensive. Some people think use of swear words make you sound uneducated (as in, you don't know a word with the meaning you need so you substitute a swear word). Especially when you are new to the language, it is easy to get confused about how extreme or mild any given word is and when it would be considered strong but appropriate versus ho-hum versus seriously out of place and offensive.